# Test strings that contain a specific pattern unless another pattern is before it

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to test a string that contains the pattern `\[[A-Z]+\]`.

But if there's a `--` before it, the string should not pass.

#### Pass

- `[GET] test`
- `test [POST] test`
- `test [POST] --test`
- `test [GET] test --test [DELETE] test`

> Even there's a `--` before `[DELETE]`, but there's no `--` before `[GET]` so it still counts

#### Fail

- `test test`
- `--[GET] test`
- `test --[GET] test`
- `test --test [PUT] test`

I tried `^(?!.*--.*\[[A-Z]+\]).*\[[A-Z]+\]` but it fails `test [GET] test --test [DELETE] test`

Here's a project on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ahO75S/1/)

Is there a regex can test this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^(?:(?!--).)*\[[A-Z]+\]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ahO75S/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(?!--)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have `--`
  - `.`: Match any character
- `)*`: End non-capture group. Match 0 or more of this group
- `\[[A-Z]+\]`: Match `[` followed by upper case followed by `]`

---

**Alternatively** you may also use this regex with PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
--.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\[[A-Z]+\]
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/ahO75S/4)

Comment: Ii was thinking about the skip fail :-) ++

Comment: Tried skip fail, maybe `--.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\[[A-Z]+\]` is good enough? :)

Comment: Indeed `--.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\[[A-Z]+\]` will work well for all the cases

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be

```
^[^-[]*(?:(?:\[(?![A-Z]+])|-(?!-))[^-[]*)*\[[A-Z]+]
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^-[]*` Optionally match any char except `[` and `-`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\[(?![A-Z]+])` Match `[` when not directly followed by `A-Z]`
    - `|` Or
    - `-(?!-)` Match - when not direcly followed by `-`
  - `)` Close non capture group
  - `[^-[]*` Optionally match any char except `[` and `-`
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `\[[A-Z]+]` Match 1+ chars A-Z between square brackets

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pr6R08/1)

Comment: But this will also skip `test [1] [POST] --test`

Comment: @anubhava I see, this will be better I think https://regex101.com/r/Pr6R08/1

Comment: indeed, you may please update in answer as well